# Thymeleaf strips id from entity on post in Spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a customerDto which has a child object customerAddress. I simply want to update the customerDto (including customerAddress). 
The problem I have is hibernate is inserting a new customerAddress row for every update query on customer. This is because the thymleaf view is not returning the customerAddress id (primary key).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "findcustomer")
public String findCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customerDto") CustomerDto customerDto, Model model) {
    CustomerDto customerDto = service.search(customerDto);
    model.addAttribute("customerDto", customerDto); // I can see customerAddress id sent to view here.
return "mypage";
}
```

mypage Form:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{updatecustomer}" th:object="${customerDto}">
    <label>Email: </label><input type="text" th:field="*{email}" />
    <label>Address Line 1</label><input type="text" th:field="*{customerAddress.lineOne}"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>


@RequestMapping(value = "updatecustomer")
public String updateCus(@ModelAttribute("customerDto") CustomerDto customerDto, Model model){
// the customerAddress id within the customerDto is null here 
    customerDto = service.updateCustomer(customerDto);

    model.addAttribute("savedCus", customerDto);
    return "updatedCustomerPage"
}
```

Service:

```
Customer customer = repository.findCustomer(customerDto.getNumber());
modelMapper.map(customerDto, customer);
repository.saveAndFlush(customer);
```

As I am using ModelMapper to map from customerDto to customer in my service. The customer entity object ends up having null customerAddress id which results in a new row in DB.

So - how can the customerAddress object maintain its attributes from view back to controller? Is my approach to this correct? I can manually map from customerDto to customer but I want to avoid this. I want the model mapper to do this.

Comment: I'd recommend you change the title of the question to something like, "Thymeleaf strips id from entity on post" instead.  People that know Hibernate can't help you here because you've already diagnosed the problem.  You want someone that knows spring-mvc / thymeleaf instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pace's comment above which made me rethink the problem and debug again. The problem is if entity attributes (not just id) are not present in the post request spring controller obviously won't know what to bind to the entity. There are two possible solutions in my view.

1. Make the attributes hidden in form which will be submitted during post call.
2. Save the attributes in session.

I prefer to go with the second option because the hidden fields can be manipulated in browser dev tools before form submission and also attributes that are not needed in view shouldn't be sent to view, it looks hacky. I will save the non-ui attributes in session and retrieve them back when form is submitted.